# How to apply cycle to this div's

Tags: django-templates

Since there is no modulus (%) in django templates So how to apply 
cycle at this

```
{% for story in data %}
   {{forloop.counter}}
```

when forloop.counter%4==1 then this  should be executed

```
    <div class="thumb">
    <a href="#"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/thumb.jpg" width="185" height="185" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbFooter">
    <span class="view">
    <a href="#" class="viewIcon">{{ story.views }}</a>
    </span>
    <span class="like">
    <a href="#" class="likeIcon">{{ story.likes }}</a>
    </span>
    </div>

    </li>
```

when forloop.counter%4==2 or 3 then this

should be executed

```
    <li>
    <div class="thumb">
    <a href="#"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/thumb.jpg" width="185" height="185" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbFooter">
    <span class="view">
    <a href="#" class="viewIcon">{{ story.views }}</a>
    </span>
    <span class="like">
    <a href="#" class="likeIcon">{{ story.likes }}</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    </li>
```

when forloop.counter%4==0 of for loop this  should be executed

```
    <li class="omega">
    <div class="thumb">
    <a href="#"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/thumb.jpg" width="185" height="185" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbFooter">
    <span class="view">
    <a href="#" class="viewIcon">{{ story.views }}</a>
    </span>
    <span class="like">
    <a href="#" class="likeIcon">{{ story.likes }}</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    </li>

    <div class="clear"></div>

   {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can build your own custom filter**

In the templatetags directory of your Django, add a file named 'mod.py'. In that file add the following code:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

def mod(value, arg):
    if value % arg == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

register.filter('mod', mod)
```

In your template use the mod filter like this:

```
...
{% load mod %}
...
<tr bgcolor="{% if forloop.counter|mod:2 %}#cccccc{% else %}#ffffff">
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want `class='omega'` on each 4th `li` of `forloop`. Use django [Cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#cycle) in template in this way,

```
{% for story in data %}
  <li {% cycle '' '' '' 'class="omega"' %}>
    <div class="thumb">
    <a href="#"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/thumb.jpg" width="185" height="185" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbFooter">
    <span class="view">
    <a href="#" class="viewIcon">{{ story.views }}</a>
    </span>
    <span class="like">
    <a href="#" class="likeIcon">{{ story.likes }}</a>
    </span>
    </div>
  </li>

    {% cycle '' '' '' '<div class="clear"></div>' %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use the [divisibleby](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#divisibleby) filter.  You can also use the [add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter to adjust for all your conditions:

> when forloop.counter%4==1 then this should be executed

```
{% if forloop.counter|add:"-1"|divisibleby:"4" %}
```

> when forloop.counter%4==2 or 3 then this

```
{% if forloop.counter|add:"-2"|divisibleby:"4" or forloop.counter|add:"-3"|divisibleby:"4" %}
```

And without using `add` for the ones divisible by 4:

> when forloop.counter%4==0 of for loop this should be executed

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4" %}
```

Comment: there is a `forloop.counter0` a zero-index loop counter that is available.